# Activating hover on image inside button when only button is hovered over?

Tags: html, css, image, button

If I have a button with an image inside of it how can I activate the image hover when the cursor is hovered over the button but not the image itself?

This is what I have so far:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-normal"><img src="images/contents/123.png"onmouseover="this.src='images/contents/123-hover.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/contents/123.png'" class="image" /></div>
```

css:

```
.btn-normal {
    background-color: #eee;
    padding: 15px!important;
    width: 250px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
.btn-normal:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}
.image {
    background-color: #ccc;
}
.image:hover {
    background-color: #009fe3;
}
```

Really at a loss with this - any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can't think of a way using CSS. JS would be optimal I think.

Comment: To target the image inside the button when the button is hovered, you could do `.btn-normal:hover .image {...}`.

Answer (score 0):

try this
HTML file

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function mouseoverImage()
{
document.getElementById('img').src='images/contents/123-hover.png';
}
 function mouseoutImage()
{
document.getElementById('img').src='images/contents/123.png';
}
</script>
<button class="btn btn-normal" onmouseover="mouseoverImage()" onmouseout="mouseoutImage()"><img id="img" class="image" src="images/contents/123.png"/></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Think I've figured it out with css... I'm thinking background-image: on the button should work. Hopefully!...

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Henrik in the comments above, .btn:hover .image selector should work for you. I have created a simple [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rxqkjzLa/) with your code. I have added a border style to the image element on hover of btn. And it works.

```
.btn:hover .image{border:1px solid red;}
```